Can i get my tokens i made on my wallet?
I trying make a token according to official document I faced this part
https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/how-to-create-a-token#mint-tokens
Look at picture first i should make an account then i can mint it

But actually how can i have access to amount i minted ? I mean it doesn't give me any secret key for wallet
So if i delete my system and use another pc i can mint?!
I would like to make a token on main net network but i confused I am afraid that my token will be easily hacked

You have to understand how clusters work. There are 4 important clusters that you need to know:

Local cluster: this is usually what you use in most tutorials
Devnet cluster: this is what you use before you launch in Mainnet to test everything out publicly. In this cluster, your friends can test your work by asking them to switch into Devnet (most wallets like Phantom gives you an option to switch into this cluster)
Mainnet cluster: this is the real thing, aka. production environment. you publish your work and pay real SOL to deploy your programs
Testnet cluster: you do not need this for now

Check your Solana config first to know if you are using a local cluster (the RPC URL:
solana config get

If you want to test your token publicly, switch to devnet:
solana config set -u devnet


But actually how can i have access to amount i minted ? I mean it doesn't give me any secret key for wallet

If you do that solana config get, it will also display where your keypair wallet file is (under Keypair Path, the .json file). That keypair is usually has the "mint authority" over your newly created token.

Thank you so much for help, because i would like to lunch token on main net network i have some concerns about security so anybody else can't mint my token and if i delete my system I can't mint my token amymore ?

you just have to keep your keypair.json as stated above. try to locate it using solana config get - if you make a backup of that file you should be able to mint with the same authority that minted the token (withtin the same cluster). if you do not want anybody to mint more supply of that token (including you) just set the mint authority of that token to none.
